# What font is used in the old Ben Sherman logo?

Tags: logo, font-identification

What font is used in the old Ben Sherman logo below?

[image: Ben Sherman Old Logo]

Comment: Hi Kshitij, we have some [requirements](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2366) for font identification questions, please take a look and [edit] your question to include that information. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It's not a font. It's a custom designed logo-type. Sorry.